# How to make these websockets work asynchronously?

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I do not know much about asynchrony, I tried to turn for loops into async for, but now only 
     the first element of the generator is working, the rest are ignored. What is wrong with 
     this code?

```
async def get_requests(self, data, request_type):
    for x in data:
        r = [
            'subscribe_on_model',
            {
                'collection': None,
                'id': None,
                'recursive': ''
            }
        ]

        r[1]['collection'] = request_type
        r[1]['id'] = x

        yield r

async def get_results(self):
    async with BaseWebsocket(self.uri) as ws:
        await ws.receive()
        sport_keys = list(self.sports.keys())
        sport_values = list(self.sports.values())

        bundle_requests = self.get_requests(sport_values, 'LineSport')
        async for bundle_request in bundle_requests:
            results = []
            sport_name = sport_keys[sport_values.index(bundle_request[1]['id'])]
            b_request = [bundle_request]
            await ws.send(b_request)
            b_response = await ws.receive()
            bundle_ids = b_response[0][1].get('lineCountryIds')

            if bundle_ids:
                championship_requests = self.get_requests(bundle_ids, 'LineCountry')
                async for championship_request in championship_requests:
                    c_request = [championship_request]
                    await ws.send(c_request)
                    c_response = await ws.receive()
                    championship_ids = c_response[0][1].get('lineChampionshipIds')
                    if championship_ids:
                        event_requests = self.get_requests(championship_ids, 'LineChampionship')
```

Comment: It's very hard to say what's wrong with a code without ability to run it. Please condider providing a [Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Also, have you tried debugging the code yourself, for example by placing `print`s at strategic places to tell you how far the program might have progressed before mysteriously stopping? If you are catching exceptions, be sure to log them. If you are spawning tasks, be sure to await them. If you get warnings along the lines of "Task was destroyed but it is pending", be sure to mention them in the question.